# Spring boot thymeleaf email does not include CSS

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

my html file structure:

```
main
-resources
  -static
    -css
      -email.css
  -templates
    -base.html
    -registration.html
```

`base.html` is a common fragment holder including links, header, footer.

```
<head th:fragment="common_head(title)">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/email.css" th:href="@{css/email.css}" type="text/css"/>       
    <title th:replace="${title}">Email</title>
</head>
```

In my `registration.html`, I tried to re-use the setting in `base.html`

```
...
<head th:replace="base :: common_head(~{::title})">
    <title>Welcome Email</title>
</head>
...
```

The email sending function is working fine, I can receive a non-css email message in my mailbox. The css link in `base.html` is correct, I can see the css style if I open directly `base.html` in the browser.
So why css does not work in `registration.html`?

**Update:**

I added an additional style placeholder in `base.html`.

```
<head th:fragment="common_head(title, styles)">
   ...
   <th:block th:replace="${styles}"/>
</head>
```

I updated `registration.html` with additional style block.

```
<head th:replace="base :: common_head(~{::title},~{::style})">
  ...
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  ...
  </style>
</head>
```

But the style in the registration seems not working. What's the problem here?

Comment: Most email clients don't support custom styles within the `<head>` section (or anything within the `<head>`). Additionally, the CSS file won't be available within the email either. Even if you would host it, most email clients would ignore it as well if I'm not mistaken. The most common solution is to use inline CSS (either using the `style` attribue or by using a `<style>` block).

Comment: @g00glen00b updated using style only, still not working.